# Как сделать фиксированный текст и кнопку на слайдере?

Tags: html, css, slider

Я новичок в программировании и мне нужно добавить слайдер прямо под шапку, вы наверное подумаете "ну слайдер и слайдер, почему нельзя добавить?" но это не простой слайдер здесь. 1 я никогда не работал со слайдерами 2 как известно обычно если на слайдере есть текст то при перелистывании картинки он меняется или перемещается Но в этом слайдере текст статичен и при перелистывании картинки он не только не меняется но и тоже не двигается то же касается и кнопки под ним. профессионалы в html&css подумают, что это глупый вопрос, но я никогда таким не занимался и ответа в интернете не нашел (прошу простить за возможно глупый вопрос, я новичок)

[image]

мой код:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #000;
  }
  
  /* header */
  
  .header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  .header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .header li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
   
  .header li a:hover,
  .header .menu-btn:hover {
    color:green;
  }

  
  .header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:green;
    
  }

  .logo::before {
   
    content:url('imgonline-com-ua-Resize-HhpRdaDieHxuk8.png');
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 3px;
            vertical-align: middle;
          }
  
  /* menu */
  
  .header .menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  }
  
  
.icons{
/*   display:block; */
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
  float:right;
  padding:16px;
  margin-right:50px;
  
/*   clear:both; */
  
}
ion-icon{
  font-size:25px;
}

.search{
  border:none;
}
.search::placeholder{
  font-size
}


  /* menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
    width: 18px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    top: -5px;
  }
  
  /* menu btn */
  
  .header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
    max-height: 240px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* 48em = 768px */
  
  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .header li {
      float: left;
    }
    .header li a {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    .header .menu {
      clear: none;
      float: center;
      max-height: none;
    }
    .header .menu-icon {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
  logo:before {
      content:url(images/quotemarks.png);
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Shop</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">Fresh market</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <div class="icons">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search.." type="text">
<ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
      
<ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="bag-handle-outline"></ion-icon>
</div>
  </ul>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```